# Get only the top 1 per non-unique column per row, per clientid, based on data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have the table `ClientStatusHistory`

This contains the history of the status changes of a specific `Client`.

The table looks like this:

(Dates in format: DD/MM/YYYY)

ClientStatusHistory:

(There is an autoincrement PK column called ID)

```
ClientID | StatusID | DateStarted | DateEnded
1        | 5        | 01/01/2000  | 01/01/2019
1        | 7        | 01/01/2019  | 11/01/2019
1        | 8        | 11/01/2019  | Null
2        | 5        | 01/01/2000  | 01/01/2019
2        | 7        | 01/01/2019  | 11/01/2019
2        | 8        | 11/01/2019  | Null
```

All the rows/records that are reflective of their current status have Null in their DateEnded column.

How would I pull all of their status before their current one, and insert it into a temporary table?

I was thinking of using `top 1`, but that will just pull out 1 record in the way I'm using it:

```
select top 1 clientid, statusid, datestarted, dateended
from ClientStatusHistory
where
dateended is not null
order by id desc
```

This will order them using `desc` from most recent to oldest, and then pull the one before that which is currently active as we ignore the nulls.

How would I expand the above query to pull all of the rows from ClientStatusHistory where the status is the one before the row with a `null` `DateEnded` field, for each `ClientID`?

Comment: Try it with an SQL Window Function: `select * from (select ..., rank() over (partition by clientId order by dateended desc) as pos from ... where dateended is not null) foo where foo.pos = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses window functions.  But I think a `join` also works:

```
select csh_prev.*
from ClientStatusHistory csh join
     ClientStatusHistory csh_prev
     on csh.clientid = csh_prev.clientid and
        csh.datestarted = csh_prev.dateended
where csh.dateended is null;
```

With window functions:

```
select csh.*
from (select csh.*,
             lead(dateended) over (partition by clientid order by datestarted) as next_dateended
      from ClientStatusHistory csh 
     ) csh
where next_dateended is null;
```

Comment: No and I don't know why it's unaccepted. My comment is also gone: "I love this answer with window functions it suits my needs perfectly" was roughly what it was

Answer (score 2):

You want `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties cs.*
from ClientStatusHistory cs
where dateended is not null
order by row_number() over (partition by ClientID  order by id desc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`:

```
;WITH AvailableClients AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT C.ClientID FROM ClientStatusHistory AS C
)
SELECT
    C.ClientID,
    T.*
FROM
    AvailableClients AS C
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            H.*
        FROM
            ClientStatusHistory AS H
        WHERE
            C.ClientID = H.CLientID AND
            H.DateEnded IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY
            H.DateEnded DESC) AS T
```

`CROSS/OUTER APPLY` is basically an "*on the go*" **result set** function that you can write that gives you the chance to link a column from another result set (the client list in this case). You can use `TOP` and `ORDER BY` for this.

The difference between `CROSS` and `OUTER` is analogous to `INNER` and `LEFT` (joins).

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number` window function

```
select * from    
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by ClientID order by DateEnded desc) rn
from t
) where t.rn=1
```